# Bootstrap navbar style changes on scroll in ReactJS app not working

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm using a [bootstrap theme](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/freelancer/) into ReactJS app. Everything works except the NavBar transition/animation effect on scrolling isn't working. I have noticed in the [projects GitHub](https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer) they are using a [script](https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/master/src/js/scripts.js). They are referring this script in the [index.html](https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/master/dist/index.html) page (the last line within the body tag).

Now, I'm trying to get it working in my ReactJS app but without luck so far. I've created a navbar component and imported into App.JS. I've used same id, "mainNav" for the  tag with in my navbar component, but I've noticed that an error in the [script](https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer/blob/master/src/js/scripts.js). It says "undefined is not an object(evaluating '$("#mainNav").offset().top > 100)' in the browser.

Could you please point me what I'm doing wrong? How can I get the same effect using ReactJS?